# Arduino Pro Micro not uploading any code (avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied)

Tags: arduino

I tried uploading any kind of sketch (including the bare bones one), and nothing worked. Other people said this error was caused by a lack of permissions on the port, and so I did what was suggested by several others and the arduino site (for linux).

```
Sketch uses 3462 bytes (12%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 149 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2411 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/ttyACM0
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyS4, } / {/dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyS4, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyS4, } / {/dev/ttyS4, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyS4, } / {/dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyS4, } => {/dev/ttyACM0, }
Found upload port: /dev/ttyACM0
/home/kalin/Downloads/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/kalin/Downloads/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino_build_767551/sketch_feb05a.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/kalin/Downloads/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/kalin/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

From the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc6):

> Open Terminal and type:
>
> ls -l /dev/ttyACM* you will get something like:
>
> crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 5 apr 23.01 ttyACM0 The "0" at the
> end of ACM might be a different number, or multiple entries might be
> returned. The data we need is "dialout" (is the group owner of the
> file).
>
> Now we just need to add our user to the group:
>
> sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER then:
>
> sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0 You will need to log out and log in again
> for this change to take effect.

However every time I launched arduino, the permissions would be cleared back to what it was before. If I ran arduino as sudo it worked, but I obviously shouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced enough to know what programmer to use for the arduino, but the issue was I was using "AVR ISP", but when I switched to "ArduinoISP" everything uploaded perfectly. There was no need to change any permissions.

Comment: this doesn't make sense. if you don't use a hardware programmer with "Upload using programmer" then the programmer selection has no use.